# How to make a recursive routine that prints the root of a BST?

Tags: data-structures, binary-search-tree

I have to write a routine that prints the root of a binary search tree in a recursive way. The function has the form

```
printTheRoot() {

    printTheRoot(someNode)

}

printTheRoot(Node node) {

     ....

}
```

I am not looking for specific code, just for an idea or pseudo-code on how this could be done. Personally, I do not think recursion is necessary but it is a requirement for this assignment.

Comment: Is there a specific way your assignment says to print it? Like in-order, pre-order or post-order. I probably suggest in-order Recursion isn't necessary but it shows skills.

Comment: @Krukusa - he says to print the root of the BST, not the whole tree, so I think he just has to walk to the root and print it.

Comment: "Printing the root" definitely doesn't need to be recursive in most tree implementations. I would assume you're supposed to [traverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) the tree, printing all nodes, but this is definitely something to clarify with whomever gave you the assignment. If, however, you don't have direct access to the root, a recursive function might make a bit more sense, but you'll need to provide a more complete code sample to illustrate how your data is represented. Either way, I don't think this question can be answered in its current state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `node` have a property `parent`? And if it does, is that property of type `Node`? If so, the answer should be obvious to you (if you're comfortable with recursion).

Remember that all recursive functions must have an exit condition. What do you think the exit condition for this function should be?

Comment: Is this a comment or an answer?

Comment: The poster said "I am not looking for specific code, just for an idea or pseudo-code on how this could be done," making it clear that it was a school assignment. I pointed out what he needed to focus on to solve the assignment. He marked it as the answer.

Comment: I am starting to think that the requirement to make this routine recursive is a mistake on part of the instructor. It just does not make sense since the root can be accessed directly. I thought that I was missing something obvious and that is why I asked this question. Moreover, this answer makes sense to what I asked assuming that we need to print the root given some arbitrary node.

Comment: Probably the assignment is mostly about learning to use recursion. Imagine that you were trying to find out what level of the tree a particular node is at. You might best accomplish that by using a recursive function that increments a counter `RowLevel` each time you recurse and returns the value of `RowLevel` when you reach the root.